# Install Ubuntu 20.04 Server from a partiton on a RHEL 7 core programmatically

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, system-installation

I have an OS which has installed RHEL7 Core.

I mounted temporary the "Ubuntu 20.04 Server" installer. I created a bootable
partition "/mnt/ubuntubt" and I copied from the mounted image in it, excepting the boot.

For boot I'm using GRUB 1 for legacy reasons.

I created a secondary ram image "custom-init" that loads some files that I need, plus a folder `cdrom/nocloud` where I have the config file `user-data` and `meta-data`.

In `menu.lst` I have:

```
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud
  initrd /casper/initrd custom-init
```

I tried to use a "s" (seedfrom short version) just `/cdrom`, as standalone location in root, but is not working.

The boot starts, but fails when it loads `init` on line 49 because is trying to load the cdrm `dev\sr0` but it is not found.

Comment: Interesting question. 
Did you try / look for anything? 
What did you find?

Comment: I tried different solutions, sending kernel parameters, modify initramfs, but I didn't found a good solution

Comment: If you post what you tried, and the results, you increase the chances of getting your problem solved.

Comment: The question seems similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251079/how-do-i-boot-from-iso-file-stored-on-hard-disk

Comment: @jmary the problem is that all solutions that I found use grub2, unfortunately I need to support also grub1; the second thing is that I mount the iso file, to add modification to initdr, so I'm trying to boot from an unpacked and modified iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't able to install ubuntu from `/tmp` mount point. I would prefer mount Ubuntu iso as loopback partition. You can mount Ubuntu iso as separate loopback partition and make entry in grub boot loader to start Ubuntu installation. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) is official Ubuntu documentation about it.

Comment: the problem is that all solutions that I found use grub2, unfortunately I need to support also grub1; the second thing is that I mount the iso file, to add modification to initdr, so I'm trying to boot from an unpacked and modified iso

Comment: RHEL 7 has grub2 bootloader and possible to install it or reinstall it. There would be no difference if you are using modified iso file.

Comment: I would also suggest you to test your modified iso in virtual environment to check whether it has any boot issues .

Comment: @user3541631 so, theoretically if you had your modified initdr on an ISO, would you be able to boot from it ? or does it have be a boot from the harddisk ? Because the are quite easy ways to build your own Live CD/Install Iso..